# getting a string length that contains unicode character exceeding 0xffff

Tags: javascript, unicode

I’m using this character, double sharp `''` which unicode is 0x1d12a.
If I use it in a string, I can’t get the correct string length:

```
str = "F"
str.length // returns 3, even though there are 2 characters!
```

How do I get the function to return the correct answer, whether or not I’m using special unicode or not ?

Comment: `"̉mủt̉ả̉̉̉t̉ẻd̉W̉ỏ̉r̉̉d̉̉".length == 24` - some chars are longer than expected

Comment: Here's a [nice blog on the topic](https://blog.jonnew.com/posts/poo-dot-length-equals-two)

Comment: It depends on what are you looking for. In Javascript, a string is made by a series of 16-bit characters "old" unicode characters. So Unicode code point above 0xffff are encoded as UCS-2, with "surrogates. So two old Unicode characters. New unicode supports code points to 10FFFF, so we have UTF-16, and we should could characters are code point. [Without considering combining characters and in general count of glyphs]

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: "*Unicode code point above 0xffff are encoded as UCS-2*" - no, they are encoded as UTF-16.  UCS-2 predates UTF-16 and does not support codepoints > U+FFFF, which is why UTF-16 was created.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: it depends on the point of view. With UTF-16, one should consider for consistency just one char per code point. Many languages predates UTF-16, so they encode with UCS-2. On UCS-2 you have "surrogates" (but officially no support of code point outside BMP, it is a compatibility trick on design of UTF-16: being byte compatible with UCS-2). On UTF-16 surrogates do not exists.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi We clearly have a difference of opinions on this matter. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The Javascript (ECMAscript 1): "A conforming implementation of this Standard shall interpret characters in conformance with the Unicode Standard, Version 3.0 or later and ISO/IEC 10646-1 with either UCS-2 or UTF-16 as the adopted encoding form, implementation level 3.", so not solving the issue ;-) https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-2  MDM pages are more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sumarize my comments:

That's just the lenght of that string.

Some chars involve other chars as well, even if it looks like a single character. `"̉mủt̉ả̉̉̉t̉ẻd̉W̉ỏ̉r̉̉d̉̉".length == 24`

From [this (great) blog post](https://blog.jonnew.com/posts/poo-dot-length-equals-two), they have a function that will return correct length:

```js
function fancyCount(str){
  const joiner = "\u{200D}";
  const split = str.split(joiner);
  let count = 0;
    
  for(const s of split){
    //removing the variation selectors
    const num = Array.from(s.split(/[\ufe00-\ufe0f]/).join("")).length;
    count += num;
  }
    
  //assuming the joiners are used appropriately
  return count / split.length;
}

console.log(fancyCount("F") == 2) // true
```

Comment: You have way too much code. `console.log([..."F"].length); // 2`

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < 0x110000; i++) {let c = String.fromCodePoint(i); console.log([...c].length, c);}`

Comment: Top notch! As you can see, I referenced someone else's findings. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
String.prototype.codes = function() { return [...this].length };
String.prototype.chars = function() {
    let GraphemeSplitter = require('grapheme-splitter');
    return (new GraphemeSplitter()).countGraphemes(this);
}

console.log("F".codes());     // 2
console.log("‍❤️‍‍".codes());     // 8
console.log("❤️".codes());      // 2

console.log("F".chars());     // 2
console.log("‍❤️‍‍".chars());     // 1
console.log("❤️".chars());      // 1
```

Comment: quite an elegant solution, but doesn’t work in a few cases :
— console.log([..."❤️"].length); == 2
— console.log([..."‍❤️‍‍"].length) == 8

Comment: `"F"` is encoded in UTF-16 using 3 (not 2) codeunits: `0x0046 0xD834 0xDD2A`. `"❤️"` is encoded using 2 codeunits: `0x2764 0xFE0F`. `"‍❤️‍‍"` is encoded using 9 (not 8) codeunits: `0xD83D 0xDC69 0x200D 0x2764 0xFE0F 0x200D 0xD83D 0xDC8B 0x200D`

Comment: Albizia, I don't appreciate you amending the task in comments. Clarifications are done by [editing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51396490/edit).

Comment: Remy Lebeau, counting in code units is wrong and has been since 1993, I don't know what you want to achieve here. Please familiarise yourself with the Unicode standard.

Comment: daxim, in my original question, I didn’t have to deal with that particular issue. It was only brought by the other answer, from that blog post.

Comment: This is a really elegant solution, which introduces a >200kb dependency to count string length.  (I'm not complaining, mind you, but perspective is important.)

Answer (score 1):

That's the function I wrote to get string length in codepoint length

```
function nbUnicodeLength(string){
    var stringIndex = 0;
    var unicodeIndex = 0;
    var length = string.length;
    var second;
    var first;
    while (stringIndex < length) {

        first = string.charCodeAt(stringIndex);  // returns an integer between 0 and 65535 representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index.
        if (first >= 0xD800 && first <= 0xDBFF && string.length > stringIndex + 1) {
            second = string.charCodeAt(stringIndex + 1);
            if (second >= 0xDC00 && second <= 0xDFFF) {
                stringIndex += 2;
            } else {
                stringIndex += 1;
            }
        } else {
            stringIndex += 1;
        }

        unicodeIndex += 1;
    }
    return unicodeIndex;
}
```

Comment: Also see https://www.lighttag.io/blog/unicode-surrogate-pairs/

Answer (score -1):

Javascript (and Java) strings use UTF-16 encoding.

Unicode codepoint U+0046 (`F`) is encoded in UTF-16 using 1 codeunit: `0x0046`

Unicode codepoint U+1D12A () is encoded in UTF-16 using 2 codeunits (known as a "surrogate pair"): `0xD834 0xDD2A`

That is why you are getting a `length` of 3, not 2.  The `length` counts the number of encoded codeunits, not the number of Unicode codepoints.