# How to get the correct element from a unicode string?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I want to get specific letters from an unicode string using index. However, it doesn't work as expected.

Example:

```js
var handwriting = `1234567890`
var normal = `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890` 

console.log(normal[3]) // gives 'd' but
console.log(handwriting[3]) // gives '�' instead of ''
```

also length doesn't work as expected `normal.length` gives correct value as **62** but `handwriting.length` gives **114.**

Indexing doesn't work as expected. How can I access the elements of unicode array?

I tried this on python it works perfectly but in Javascript it is not working.

I need exact characters from the unicode string like an expected output of 'd' '' for index 3

Comment: As you have discovered, unicode characters are rarely a single byte. You'll need some way of parsing the unicode bytes and picking "characters" from that.

Comment: Related: https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/

Comment: @phuzi picking the characters is the real problem here.

Comment: Note: It is not handwriting (it mathematical notation), and you should not use Unicode for formatting: you will create much more problems. Unicode is about semantic. Use fonts (and markup) for formatting. You may use standard Unicode decomposition to get from math to letters (which is much more generalized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Javascript, a string is a sequence of 16-bit code points. Since these characters are encoded above the Basic Multilingual Plane, it means that they are represented by a pair of code points, also known as a surrogate pair.

[Reference](https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/)

Unicode number of  is `U+1D586`. And 0x1D586 is greater than 0xFFFF (2^16). So,  is  represented by a pair of code points, also known as a surrogate pair

```js
console.log("".length)
console.log("" === "\uD835\uDD86")
```

One way is to create an array of characters using the spread syntax or `Array.from()` and then get the index you need

```js
var handwriting = `1234567890`

console.log([...handwriting][3])
console.log(Array.from(handwriting)[3])
```

Comment: … until it doesn't. Try `[...'‍❤️‍‍'].length` and the expression returns 8 instead of 1 like a human would expect. Spread count characters, not graphemes, see <https://stackoverflow.com/a/51422499/46395>. I wish the language and its designers would treat Unicode seriously, but they don't, so the programmers must suffer.

Comment: @daxim well spotted. The more I read on unicode, the more confused I get smh. If I paste the above string with emojis in the console, I see a `\u200D` empty space. Is that part of the emoji? Why do they have 3 codepoints per emoji

Comment: @adiga - It's not just emojis, anything with combining marks has the same issue. For instance, `[..."Français"][4]` is `c` (because I've written it with a `c` followed by a combining mark for the cedille, rather than using the combined `ç` character). It's...not a lot of fun. :-D `normalize` can help in cases like that one where there is a single character equivalent, but often there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

A unicode character looks like '\u00E9' so if your string is longer this is normal.
To have the real length of a unicode string, you have to convert it to an array :

```
let charArray = [...handwriting]
console.log(charArray.length) //=62
```

Each item of your array is a char of your string.
charArray[3] will return you the unicode char corresponding to ''